# Typescript with union types

Tags: typescript, types

I have a generic function `fetcher` which accepts a callback parameter. This callback will be executed in the `fetcher` function later on (I'm using Vue composables pattern here). Further, these callbacks accepts different parameters as an argument. I've typed `fetcher` callback that accepts "params" parameter  as an union type of possible params. Then I can use this `fetcher` function and pass callbacks with different parameters.

Code example:

```
type Param1 = {
  a: string;
}
type Param2 = {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}
type Params = Param1 | Param2
declare function fetcher(func: (params: Params) => void): void
declare function testFunc(obj: Param2): void
fetcher(testFunc)
```

Typescript error:

```
Argument of type '(obj: Param2) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(params: Params) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'obj' and 'params' are incompatible.
    Type 'Params' is not assignable to type 'Param2'.
      Property 'b' is missing in type 'Param1' but required in type 'Param2'.(2345)
```

How can I type `fetcher` function and pass a callback with declared params, like `Param1` or `Param2` which `fetcher` can accept?

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJzgWwIxQLxQN4FgBQUUcAXFAM7AICWAdgOYDcBAvgaJLIigEyY4EipClTpNBUAEZlKNBs3xt87cNHhJk5fupToAPlw08CBACYQAxgBtE0AGYBXWheDUA9rSh2IwCwAsIBAAKR2cyILBuTTIdTQBKTAA+KAA3N2pTOLI0jJN8c2tbLycXd09gCEoAMRKgt0kAKxionizU9NM8718A4IrqkrigA)

Comment: What is the intent here?  Is `Params2` just always more that Params1?  If so just use `Prams2` in callback signature. Functions that expect less will work  https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJzgWwIxQLxQN4FgBQUUcAXFAM7AICWAdgOYDcBAvgaJLIigEyY4EipClTpNBUAEZlKNBs3xt87cNHhJk5fupToAPlw08CBACYQAxgBtE0AGYBXWheDUA9rSh2IwCwAsIBAAKR2cyILBuTTIdZB4ASkwAPigANzdqU3iydMyTfHNrWy8nF3dPYAhKADFSoLdJACsYqIScjNMzSxsEe1LXDyhKmtKeeqaWjVRstI78718A4OHgWud4ggX-QKCVtYsEoA

Comment: "Further, these callbacks accepts different parameters as an argument." and are these different parameters mutually incompatible? Your example has `Param2 extends Param1` but if that's not true in general (e.g., maybe `Param2` should be `{a: number}`), then how would the `fetcher()` implementation know which parameters to pass to it?  This is important because while you could potentially rewrite `fetcher()`'s call signature like `((x: Param1) => void) | (x: Param2) => void)` and even do so programmatically from `Params`, such a union of functions would be almost useless in practice.

Comment: And the correct solution would be that `fetcher()` needs something like a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) input that lets the implementation know which of these callback types it's getting, so it knows how to call it.

Comment: Like, [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAjy4W) is how I might answer your question, but it would be irresponsible, and instead I'd suggest something more like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mpg9XN).  What do you want to see here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: `declare function fetcher(func: (params: Param1 & Param2) => void): void`

Explanation:

The declaration:

```
declare function fetcher(func: (params: Param1 | Param2) => void): void
```

Instructs the compiler that **func must support both Param1 and Param2** types.

Remember:

```
{ a: string; b: string } | { a: string; } !== { a: string; } & { b?: string }
```

Type union for function arguments:

1. means that the function can handle both the situations: {a} and {a,b}
2. does not mean that parameter {b} is optional, so `{a}|{a,b} != {a,b?}`

If you want to tell the compiler that fetcher accepts either `func(p: Param1)` or `func(p: Param2)` you have two possibilities:

```
// 1:
declare function fetcher(func: (params: Param1 & Param2) => void): void

// 2:
declare function fetcher(func: ((p: Param1) => void) | ((p: Param2) => void)): void
```

And the second one is more semantically correct as it tell the compiler that functions with both arguments are welcome.